# Percentage inside the pie chart instead of count

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

My data frame

```
dput(d)
structure(list(x = c("Organonitrogen compound metabolic process", 
"Cellular process", "Nitrogen compound metabolic process", "Primary metabolic process", 
"Organic substance biosynthetic process", "Metabolic process", 
"Cellular nitrogen compound biosynthetic process", "Cellular metabolic process", 
"Organic substance metabolic process", "Cellular biosynthetic process"
), freq = c(71, 119, 87, 89, 52, 94, 42, 89, 89, 49)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code I'm running to generate the pie chart

```
d$perc <- round(100 * d$freq / sum(d$freq))

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = 0, y = freq, fill = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label =  perc), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(fill = 'Type', x = NULL, y = NULL, title = 'Pathway Pie chart', subtitle = 'percentages') +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_minimal()
```

I get something like this

[image: my image]

But I would like to see something like this.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

[image: this figure with percentage inside the plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scales::percent()` is designed for this. Try

```
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(freq/sum(freq), 1)),
          position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
```

Because you have calculated the percentage as `perc`, you can pass it into `percent()` directly. (Beware of its args `accuracy` and `scale`. In your case they both should be 1)

```r
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(perc, 1, 1)),
          position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
```

You can search `?scales::percent` to see more args to adjust.

Comment: "ou have calculated the percentage as perc, you can pass it into percent()" this i was not able to do ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `theme_void` to remove axis and ticks and `sprintf` to display the percent symbol.

```r
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = 0, y = freq, fill = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label =  sprintf("%d%%",perc)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            size = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(fill = 'Type', x = NULL, y = NULL, title = 'Pathway Pie chart', subtitle = 'percentages') +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: As some technical solutions have been given already, IMO there remains a fundamental conceptual issue with the chart: what message is the viewer expected to remember from this visualisation - even after 10 s patient examination - other than *there's a whole lot going on*? ;-) There's no quantitative or qualitative order, no comparison of categories deemed important enough for categorisation (e.g. biosynthesis vs. metabolism), no apparent meaning of colour (except separating the wedges) ...

Comment: @I_O " no apparent meaning of colour (except separating the wedges)" i can't disagree tbh most biology papers are filled with such stuffs although they are meaningless we still just generate to fill up the spaces in panels